# Is it possible to keep seperate two HTML pages, combine them somehow to create a scroll down effect into the other pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to research online right now and see if it is possible to combine my current project and basically get my index page to scroll down into my home page and then into my contact if the person chooses too or they can use the "button" in the index page I am still working on.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="ghost.ico">



    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-137617043-2"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-137617043-2');
</script>



    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-PTZXGBD');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

<!--- Google Tag Manager -->
</head>

<main>
<body>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <section class="showcase">
        <div class="video-container thick-green-border">
            <video autoplay loop muted playsinline
            class="video-background">
            <source src="coiblue.m4v" type="video/mp4" alt="Gx0st"></video>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
             <a href="home.html" class="btn">
            <img class="smaller-image" src="wh.png" alt="GhostRobles Portfolio @GhostRobles">
        </a>
            </div>      
    </section>

    <!-- Lets get mobile viewport -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta content="True" name="HandheldFriendly"/>
<meta id="viewport-tag" name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, viewport-fit=cover"/>

</main>


    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PTZXGBD"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) --> 

<style> 

.thick-green-border {
    border-color: rgb(13, 214, 13);
    border-width: 15px 5px 15px 5px;
    border-style: dashed;
  }


.smaller-image {

    width: 150px;
    
}
    

@font-face 
{font-family: 'vcr_osd_mono-webfont'; 
src: url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.eot'); 
src: url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('webfont.svg#svgFontname') format('svg');} * {
font-display: swap;
}


    :root {
    --primary-color: #000000;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: "vcr_osd_mono-webfont";
    line-height: 1.5;
    cursor: url(https://cur.cursors-4u.net/toons/too-3/too297.cur), auto;
}


a {
  font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--primary-color);
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgb(255, 0, 0);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.showcase {
    height: 100vh; /* changes image top to bottom */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.video-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: var(--primary-color) url('behindit.m4v') no-repeat center
        center/contain; /* changed from cover to contain */ 
}

.video-container video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    object-fit: contain;
}

.video-container:after {
    content: '';
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: static;
}

.content {
    z-index: 2;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 5px 5px 2px;
    background: var(--primary-color);
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: dashed rgb(255, 0, 0) 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    opacity: 0.85;
    margin-top: -450px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 20px black;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.btn:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2); /* this changes the button hover */
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0; /* fixed, note, don't add another repository. */
}

    </style>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- START NAV -->
<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="Bax.ico">






  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-137617043-2"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-137617043-2');
</script>




  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
  new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
  'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-PTZXGBD');</script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<nav id="menu" class="nav">
  <div class="nav-list"> 
      <a style="font-size: 25px" href="https://www.youtube.com/c/ghostrobles">Youtube</a>

      <a style="font-size: 25px" href="https://www.twitch.tv/ghostrobless">Twitch</a> 
    
      <a style="font-size: 25px" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- END NAV -->

<!-- Lets get mobile viewport -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta content="True" name="HandheldFriendly"/>
<meta id="viewport-tag" name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, viewport-fit=cover"/>


<!-- START WELCOME SECTION -->
<!-- Background Start -->
<section class="showcase">
  <div class="video-container thin-red-border">
    <video src="LTWS.m4v" autoplay playsinline muted loop></video>
  </div> </section>

<section id="welcome-section" class="welcome-section">
  <h1>Ghost Robles</h1>
</section> <!--- removing this will collapse it -->
<!-- Background End -->
<!-- END WELCOME SECTION -->

<!-- START PROJECTS SECTION -->
  <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PTZXGBD"
  height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->

<section id="projects" class="projects-section">
  <h2 class="projects-section-header">Files</h2>
  <div class="projects-grid"> <!--- adding </div at the end will destroy the initial boxes of content-->

  <!-- Luh tyler x SleazyWorld Go (Don't Get Ya Feelings In It Behind The Scenes by Ghost Robles) -->
  <a 
  href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7tcVwjj5x0"
  target="_self"
  class="project project-tile"
  >
  <img
  class="project project-tile"
  src="quadrino.jpg"
  alt="Funny Marco, King Cid, JWondr, Luh Tyler Chilling"/>
  <p class="project-tile">
     <span class="code">&lt;</span>
     Luh Tyler x SleazyWorld G0
     <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span>
   </p>
   </a>
  <!-- Luh tyler x SleazyWorld Go (Don't Get Ya Feelings In It Behind The Scenes by Ghost Robles) -->

  <!-- Bad Trip by Lucius Arthur Directed By Katya Ganfeld -->  
  <a 
  href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kmrgKSGgN4"
  target="_self"
  class="project project-tile"
  >
  <img
  class="project project-tile"
  src="tablemafia.png"
  alt="Lucius Arthur Music Video shot in Los Angeles California by Katya Ganfeld on Kodak Film"/>
  <p class="project-tile">
     <span class="code">&lt;</span>
     BAD TRIP by Lucius Arthur
     <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span>
  </p>
  </a>
  <!-- Bad Trip by Lucius Arthur Directed By Katya Ganfeld -->  


  <!-- DaBaby Shake Sumn' Official Music Video -->
  <a
  href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZRWV3aW8pc"
  target="_self"
  class="project project-tile"
  >
  <img
   class="project project-tile"
   src="Ghost.jpg"
   alt="I shot the Behind The Scenes for this Music Video and wanted to share the Official Music Video by DaBaby"/>
  <p class="project-tile">
     <span class="code">&lt;</span>
      Shake Sumn' by DaBaby
     <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span>
  </p>
  </a>
  <!-- DaBaby Shake Sumn' Official Music Video -->

  <!-- DaBaby Selling Crack Ft. OFFSET from The Migos -->
  <a 
  href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8DUHA0Lz60"
  target="_self"
  class="project project-tile"
  >
  <img
   class="project project-tile"
   src="let3mkn0w.jpg"
   alt="DaBaby Productions with the Reel Goats and Offset from The Migos"/>
   <p class="project-tile">
      <span class="code">&lt;</span>
      SELLING CRACK ft. OFFS3T
      <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span>
   </p>
   </a>
     
  <!-- Brothel. Music Live at Los Globos in Los Angeles, CA -->
  <a
  href="https://youtu.be/g_5LIly8nVc"
  target="_self"
  class="project project-tile"
  >
  <img
   class="project project-tile"
   src="brothel.jpg"
   alt="Brothel. Music Live in Los Angeles, CA at Los Globos filmed by Ghost Robles and Spicy Rico"/>
   <p class="project-tile">
      <span class="code">&lt;</span>
      Brothel.✱Los Globos
      <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span>
   </p>
   </a>
  <!-- Brothel. Music Live at Los Globos in Los Angeles, CA -->
  
  <!-- Spicy Rico x Models Laguna Beach Visual -->
  <a
  href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihkOYtflnLQ&t=29s"
  target="_self"
  class="project project-tile"
  >
  <img
   class="project project-tile"
   src="Laguna Girl.jpg"
   alt="Going to Laguna Beach and capturing a visual with my friend Spicy Rico"/>
   <p class="project-tile">
      <span class="code">&lt;</span>
      Models x Laguna Beach
      <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span>
    </p>
    </a>
  <!-- Laguna Beach Visual with Models -->
    
  <!-- Nickmercs 500k Event in San Diego, California -->
  <a 
  href="https://youtu.be/Dt1SwK-IjpM"
  target="_self"
  class="project project-tile"
  >
  <img
   class="project project-tile"
   src="NICKMERCS.jpg"
   alt="NICKMERCS with a fan in San Diego California for his 500k Event for MFAM."/>
  <p class="project-tile">
    <span class="code">&lt;</span>
    Nickmercs 300k+ MFAM Event!
    <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span>
  </p>
  </a>
  <!-- Nickmercs 500k Event in San Diego, California -->

  <!--- OhGeesy Live at The Observatory San Diego, California (Presented by Ghost Robles)-->
  <a
  href="https://youtu.be/rTkBNso_UtY"
  target="_self"
  class="project project-tile"
  >
  <!-- Using project project-tile instead of project-image creates a barrier look -->
  <img
  class="project project-tile"                           
  src="OhGeesy.jpg"
  alt="OhGeesy Live at The Observatory in San Diego, California. Presented by Ghost Robles."
  />
  <p class="project-tile">
    <span class="code">&lt;</span>
     OTXBOYZ OhGeesy
    <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span>
  </p>
  </a>
  <!--- OhGeesy Live at The Observatory San Diego, California (Presented by Ghost Robles)-->

  <!--- Blueface and Desiigner Visual in Calabasas by Ghost Robles -->
  <a
  href="https://youtu.be/ASrD3c95MlI"
  target="_self"
  class="project project-tile"
  >
  <img 
  class="project project-tile" 
  src="Desiigner.jpg"
  alt="Blueface and Desiigner Visual filmed in Calabasas by Ghost Robles"
  />
  <p class="project-tile">
    <span class="code">&lt;</span>
    Lifestyle 91301: Visual in Calabasas
    <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span>
  </p>
  </a>
  <!--- Blueface and Desiigner Visual -->

  <!--- Coi Leray Anxiety Visual Behind the Scenes -->
  <a 
  href="https://youtu.be/gGoQEMWxLFc"
  target="_self"
  class="project project-tile"
  >
  <img 
  class="project project-tile"
  src="coicoi.jpg"
  alt="Coi Leray Anxiety Behind-the-Scenes Visual by Ghost Robles" 
  />
  <p class="project-tile">
    <span class="code">&lt;</span>
    Coi Leray "Anxiety"
    <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span>
    </p>
  </a>
  <!--- Coi Leray Anxiety Visual BTS -->
  
  <!-- "Cold December" Visual in Malibu -->
  <a 
   href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-QsWT9ZQ7o"
   target="_self"
   class="project project-tile"
  >
  <img 
  class="project project-tile"
  src="reelgoats.jpg"
  alt="Rod Wave Cold December Behind-the-Scenes Visual by Ghost Robles"
  /> 
<p class="project-tile">
  <span class="code">&lt;</span>
  "Cold December" Visual in Malibu
  <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span>
</p>
</a>
<!--- "Cold December" Visual in Malibu -->


  <!-- OG 3Three (Visual by Ghost Robles) -->
  <a 
  href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqsShaF12OA"
  target="_self"
  class="project project-tile"
  >
  <img 
  class="project project-tile"
  src="3Three.jpg"
  alt="NBA OG 3Three - Cardio Visual Behind-the-Scenes by Ghost Robles"
  />
<p class="project-tile">
  <span class="code">&lt;</span>
  NBA OG 3Three
  <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span>
</p>
</a>
<!-- OG 3Three (Visual by Ghost Robles) -->
  
  <!-- Dip With My Chips -->
  <a 
   href="https://youtu.be/hYuWfoO6RHE"
   target="_self"
   class="project project-tile"
  >
  <img
  class="project project-tile"
  src="dipwithmychips.jpg"
  alt="Lil Tracy and Big Head Live at The House of Blues in San Diego, California presented by Ghost Robles"
  />
<p class="project-tile">
  <span class="code">&lt;</span>
  Lil Tracy & Big Head
  <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span>
  </p>
</a>
<!--- Dip With My Chips -->
    
  <!-- It Takes Time --> 
   <a 
    href="https://youtu.be/NzLmU4qtFoE"
    target="_self"
    class="project project-tile"
   >
    <img 
    class="project-image"
    src="denisvibe.jpg"
    alt="Atmosphere - Woes Visual Behind-the-Scenes by Ghost Robles"
    />
  <p class="project-tile">
    <span class="code">&lt;</span>
     It Takes Time
    <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span> 
  </p>
</a>
<!-- It Takes Time --> 

  <!--- Blueface and Hardini --->
  <a 
    href="https://youtu.be/CW999c2srPw"
    target="_self"
    class="project project-tile"
  >
   <img
    class="project-image"
    src="blueface.jpg"
    alt="Blueface and Hardini Music Video Visual Behind-the-Scenes by Ghost Robles"
    />
  <p class="project-title">
    <span class="code">&lt;</span>
    Blueface and Hardini
    <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span>
  </p>
  </a>

  <!--- Blueface and Hardini --->

    <!--- Se Va by Delian --->
    <a
      href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pS1jRP3EnRo"
      target="_self"
      class="project project-tile"
    >
      <img
        class="project-image"
        src="SeVa.jpg"
        alt="Delian Se Va Music Video Visual by Ghost Robles"
      />
      <p class="project-title">
        <span class="code">&lt;</span>
        Delian - Se Va 
        <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span>
      </p>
    </a>
     <!--- Se Va by Delian --->

     <!---- BLM Peaceful Protest --->
    <a
      href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCvm1xSX4zQ"
      target="_self"
      class="project project-tile"
    >
      <img
        class="project-image"
        src="BLMbalboa.jpg"
        alt="BLM Peaceful Protest at Balboa Park in San Diego, California."
      />
      <p class="project-title">
        <span class="code">&lt;</span>
        BLM Peaceful Protest
        <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span>
      </p>
    </a>
    <!---- BLM Peaceful Protest  --->


<!-- Day by Day -->
    <a
      href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7kirbxR_Is"
      target="_self"
      class="project project-tile"
    >
      <img
        class="project-image"
        src="daybyday.jpg"
        alt="project"
      />
      <p class="project-title">
        <span class="code">&lt;</span>
        Day by Day (ft. Phaze Jones)
        <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span>
      </p>
    </a>
 
<!-- Day by Day -->
</div> <!-- If you add div under section, it moves "Show All" for some reason-->

 <a
    href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSM3fpzXloGLNL7N6qnjamA"
    class="btn btn-show-all"
    target="_self"> Show All </a>
  

</section>


<!-- END PROJECTS SECTION -->


<!-- START FOOTER SECTION -->

<footer>
  <p>
    Love Yourself
  </p>
  <p>
    &copy; Coded by 
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSM3fpzXloGLNL7N6qnjamA" target="_blank"
      >GhostRobles</a>
  </p>
</footer>
</head>

<!-- END FOOTER SECTION -->

<body>
<style>

/* Stills */ 

/* Stills */



/* project hover */
a:hover {color: red;}
/* project hover */

/* Custom properties/variables  */
:root {
  --main-white: #ffffff;
  --main-red: red;
  --main-blue: #45567d;
  --main-gray: #303841;
}

/* Base reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* box-sizing and font sizing */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;

  /* Set font size for easy rem calculations
   * default document font size = 16px, 1rem = 16px, 100% = 16px
   * (100% / 16px) * 10 = 62.5%, 1rem = 10px, 62.5% = 10px
  */
  font-size: 45.5%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/* A few media query to set some font sizes at different screen sizes.
 * This helps automate a bit of responsiveness.
 * The trick is to use the rem unit for size values, margin and padding.
 * Because rem is relative to the document font size
 * when we scale up or down the font size on the document
 * it will affect all properties using rem units for the values.
*/

/* I am using the em unit for breakpoints
 * The calculation is the following
 * screen size divided by browser base font size
 * As an example: a breakpoint at 980px
 * 980px / 16px = 61.25em
*/

/* 1200px / 16px = 75em */
@media (max-width: 75em) {
  html {
    font-size: 60%;
  }
}

/* 980px / 16px = 61.25em */
@media (max-width: 61.25em) {
  html {
    font-size: 58%;
  }
}

/* 460px / 16px = 28.75em */
@media (max-width: 28.75em) {
  html {
    font-size: 55%;
  }
}

/* Base styles */

body {
  font-family: "vcr_osd_mono-webfont";
  font-size: 1.8rem; /* 18px */
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: var(--main-white);
  cursor: url(https://cur.cursors-4u.net/toons/too-3/too297.cur), auto;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-family: "vcr_osd_mono-webfont";
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
}

/* Background Text Clip */ 
h1 {
  font-size: 13vw;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "vcr_osd_mono-webfont";
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-image: url("https://media.giphy.com/media/5k00E7cigvvqnBYDdP/giphy.gif");
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
/* Background Text Clip End */ 

h2 {
  font-size: 4.2rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--main-white);
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

/* nav START */

.nav {

  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--main-black);

  /* took away box-shadow command ((box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);) that adds line under nav) */
  
  z-index: 10;
}



.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white(245, 0, 0); 
  margin: 0px 10px;
  line-height: 50px; 
  display: block;
  /* removed  border-bottom: 1px solid red;*/
  margin: 0;
  clear: auto;
}



label {
  margin: 0px 65px 0px 620px;
  font-size: 65px;
  line-height: 70px;
  display: none;
  width: 26px;
  float: auto;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;

}

#toggle:checked + .menu {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) { label { display: block; cursor: pointer;}}


.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

@media (max-width: 28.75em) {
  .nav {
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .nav-list {
    margin: 0 1rem;
  }
}

.nav-list a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  background:rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/* NAV END */

/* Welcome section */

.welcome-section {
  display: flex; /* OG one is Flex */
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 38vh; /* this will change the border in between Cinematography and Files [last was 50vh for normal]*/
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: linear-gradient(62deg, #000000 0%, #000000 100%);
}

.welcome-section > p {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: italic;
  color: red;
}

/* Projects section */

.projects-section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10rem 2rem; /* 10rem 2rem is the OG */
  background: url(textures.jpg);
}

.projects-section-header {
  max-width: 333px; /* changes the white line under files width */
  margin: 0 auto 6rem auto;
  border-bottom: 0.2rem solid black; /* 0.2 rem is OG */
}

@media (max-width: 28.75em) {
  .projects-section-header {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
}

/* "Automagic" image grid using no media queries */
.projects-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 8rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px; /* 1280px is OG*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
}

@media (max-width: 30.625em) {
  .projects-section {
    padding: 6rem 1rem;
  }

  .projects-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}

.project {
  background: black;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red;
  border-radius: 33px; /* 13px is the OG */ /* red lines project */
}

.code {
  color: var(--main-white);
  transition: color 0.3s ease-out;
}

.project:hover .code {
  color: #00ff22;
}

.project-image {
  height: calc(100% - 6.8rem);
  width: 100%; /* 100% is OG - changes image size */
  object-fit: cover;
}

.project-title {
  /*deleting font-size: 2rem; */ 
  padding: 2rem 0.5rem;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.btn-show-all {
  font-size: 2rem;
  background: black;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
}

.btn-show-all:hover {
  background: black;;
}

.btn-show-all:hover > i {
  transform: translateX(2px);
}

.btn-show-all > i {
  margin-left: 10px;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}

/* Footer */

footer {
  font-weight: 300;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: black;
  border-top: 3px solid red;
}

footer > p {
  margin: 0.5rem;  /* changes size of the footer text and width */
}

footer i {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media (max-width: 28.75em) {
  footer {
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
  }
}


/* Video Background Here */ 
.video-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 38%;
    overflow: hidden; /* if you change this, the bottom of the website will start to expand - visible */
    
}

.video-container video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
  position: cover;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-1%, -25%); /* FOUND IT! This changes files gap  OG = -5%, -50%*/
    object-fit: static;
}

.video-container:after {
    content: '';
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: static;
}
/* Video Background End */ 


.thin-red-border {
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-style: inset;
  }

  font-face {
  font-display: swap;
}

 @font-face 
 {font-family: 
  'vcr_osd_mono-webfont'; 
  src: url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.eot'); 
  src: url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.eot?#iefix') 
  format('embedded-opentype'), url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('webfont.svg#svgFontname') format('svg') ;}


a
  {text-align: auto;}

</style>


</script>
</body>
```

The page isn't the best but I am just a self-taught person who does it for fun and passion. So, any help or guidance would help.

I don't necessarily need someone to tell me the "answer" although that would be nice, I like to learn and a general direction would be great or to even know it's possible and maybe not waste my time and just combine everything into one page which seems to be the other way.

Thank you for your time and any consideration. I appreciate the Stack OverFlow Community!

**I appreciate anyone even if they contributed or not. Thank you for reading.**

I have tried researching and will continue to do so.

Comment: Well, you can have a single page application (SPA) which can be navigated through both by scrolling, or by clicking buttons in a page-header thing.
You could also store the all of the site's text in a json format, which you load and then display based upon scroll position.
I don't really see a neat (read clear and sensible) way to save HTML files and load them with your own code.

Wkipedia for instance, stores it's data in a format which allows for it to be loaded and presented for viewing by the backend. But that really only seems to be a way of reducing redundancy and making for (cont)

Comment: a format which permits easy editing.

Comment: @enhzflep thank you for your words and time spent. I see what you are saying. It seems a SPA would be nice.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a single master web page with two IFRAMEs.

Load the 1st source page into the first IFRAME.

Load the 2nd source page into the second IFRAME.